# Inheritance of several Kivy properties

Tags: python, kivy

Let's say I have 2 kivy properties

- the first property is responsible for ensuring that the value lies in a certain range (for example, from 0 to 1) - I use BoundedNumericProperty for that

```
class MyBoundedProperty(BoundedNumericProperty):
    def __init__(self, *largs, **kw):
        self._my_min = kw.get('min', 0)  # 0 is default
        self._my_max = kw.get('max', 1.)  # 1 is default
        kw['min'] = self._my_min
        kw['max'] = self._my_max
        kw['errorhandler'] = self._my_errorhandler
        super().__init__(*largs, **kw)

    def _my_errorhandler(self, x):
        return min(max(x, self._my_min), self._my_max)
```

- the second property is responsible for ensuring that the value is always rounded to the fifth order (AliasProperty)

```
class MyAliasProperty(AliasProperty):
    _data = 0

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['getter'] = self._getter
        kwargs['setter'] = self._setter
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def _getter(self, obj):
        return self._data

    def _setter(self, obj, value):
        if type(value) is int:
            value = float(value)
        if type(value) is float:
            self._data = round(value, 5)
        else:
            raise ValueError('{}.{} has an invalid format (got {!r})'.format(
                obj.__class__.__name__, self.name, value))
        return True  # Value changed, dispatch event
```

I would like to be able to reuse these properties when creating new properties, since I do it with widget behaviors.
For example:
x = MyProperty (MyBoundedProperty, MyAliasProperty)

This would mean that the value of x should be
1) within specified limits (min and max) and
2) be rounded to 5th order
at the same time.

I want to clarify - my task is not to use different properties (it may be several Alias properties for example). My task is to be able to reuse the properties created earlier for making composite properties.

Is there a way to do this?

PS let me clarify this a bit.
For example:

```
class MyRoundProperty(AliasProperty):
    _data = 0.

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['getter'] = self._getter
        kwargs['setter'] = self._setter
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def _getter(self, obj):
        return self._data

    def _setter(self, obj, value):
        if type(value) is int:
            value = float(value)
        if type(value) is float:
            pass
            self._data = round(value, 5)
        else:
            raise ValueError('{}.{} has an invalid format (got {!r})'.format(
                obj.__class__.__name__, self.name, value))
        return True  # Value changed, dispatch event
```

```
class MyBoundProperty(AliasProperty):
    _data = 0.
    _min = 0.
    _max = 1.

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self._min = kwargs.pop('min', 0.)  # 0 is default
        self._max = kwargs.pop('max', 1.)  # 1 is default
        kwargs['getter'] = self._getter
        kwargs['setter'] = self._setter
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def _getter(self, obj):
        return self._data

    def _setter(self, obj, value):
        if type(value) is int or float:
            value = min(max(value, self._min), self._max)
            self._data = value
        else:
            raise ValueError('{}.{} has an invalid format (got {!r})'.format(
                obj.__class__.__name__, self.name, value))
        return True  # Value changed, dispatch event
```

This works:

```
class MyProperty(MyRoundProperty):
    pass
```

And this works:

```
class MyProperty(MyBoundProperty):
    pass
```

But this

```
class MyProperty(MyRoundProperty, MyBoundProperty):
    pass
```

behaves only like MyRoundProperty, and I want MyProperty to have the behavior of both classes

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a 'no, but yes' situation. No, you probably can't inherit from multiple properties without issues, they will conflict in managing their internal state. But yes, you can probably achieve what you actually want in a reasonable way.

You could do this in multiple ways, I'm not really clear what you're doing and what would therefore be the best option. In the simplest case, you could just add the rounding functionality to your `MyBoundedNumericProperty`, it isn't clear to me if you actually want the functionality in a separate property. A more flexible option would be to make a mixin like a widget behaviour, probably overriding the `__set__` method of the property.

Comment: Hi, I explained a little better what I want to achieve